# Different IP addresses from an external website and from ipconfig

Tags: ip

I checked my ip address from http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup
and I also used 'ipconfig' to check my ip address.

The result are different.
I don't understand why.

Please teach me the reason, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The IP you see in ipconfig is most likely the IP address your router has assigned to your PC.
The IP address you get from a website is your external IP address, or the IP address that your ISP has assigned to your modem.